# libfixmath undefined reference

Tags: c, fixed-point

I´m trying to produce a little example code for the library libfixmath and I get the error "undefined reference to `fix16_mul' "

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libfixmath/fixmath.h"

int main(){

    fix16_t res = fix16_mul(fix16_from_int(1), fix16_from_int(2));

    return 0;
}
```

The library is at the specified path and I compile just with the command

```
gcc -o testfix testfix.c
```

Comment: You need to provide more info so that you can receive help.

Comment: what do you need to know? I´m sorry if the question is stupid, but I can´t find any real documentation or tutorial for the lib.

Comment: What is a special option in terms of gcc? Maybe what you consider special, others would consider a requirement for building your project - add the full command(s) you're using to compile your code

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.nongnu.org/fixmath/doc/index.html) says
`To use the fixmath library, include the header <fixmath/fixmath.h>, and link the application with -lfixmath, or use pkg-config to determine the compiler and linker flags.`

So change

```
gcc -o testfix testfix.c
```

to

```
gcc -o testfix testfix.c -lfixmath
```

and it should work.